# How to show information from a MySQL database in an ASP.NET page using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net to create a webapp and this is what i want to be able to do:

I think i have correctly read all of the rows of a MySQL database table and created a List of objects that contain the information from the table.

I want to display the info from the objects that are stored in the list in my page

this is what i tried:

**file.cshtml**

```
<form runat="server">
    <div id="outputDiv" runat="server">
    </div>                
</form>
```

**file.cshtml.cs**

```
public void OnPost()
{
    List<Pregunta> vect = new List<Pregunta>();

    Pregunta preg = new Pregunta();

    string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=lavaquestbd;94 Allow User Variables = True;";

    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cs))
    {
        connection.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM preguntas";
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    preg.idPregunta = reader.GetInt32("idPregunta");
                    preg.pregunta = reader.GetString("pregunta");
                    preg.respuesta1 = reader.GetString("respuesta1");
                    preg.respuesta2 = reader.GetString("respuesta2");
                    preg.respuesta3 = reader.GetString("respuesta3");
                    preg.respuesta4 = reader.GetString("respuesta4");
                    preg.correcta = reader.GetInt32("correcta");

                    vect.Add(preg);
                }

                foreach (Pregunta pregunta in vect)
                {
                    outputDiv.InnerHtml += $"<p>{pregunta.respuesta2}</p>";
                }
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to all of this, so i'm sorry if i didn't explain myself well.

Comment: You keep rewiting the contents of the one 'preg' instance. Use `new` *inside* the loop

Answer (score 0):

In that line `vect.Add(preg);` you are not adding the bunch of property-values that you have set in the lines above, but a *reference* to the instance where you updated those values.

However, you only have one instance that you created outside of the loop, at the start : `Pregunta preg = new Pregunta();`

So you keep updating the property-values of that one instance and adding that one instance to the list (again). The end result is a list of identical values, from the last row read.

The solution is simple: move that declaration/initialisation row *inside* the loop:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Pregunta preg = new Pregunta();

    preg.idPregunta = reader.GetInt32("idPregunta");
    // snip

    vect.Add(preg);
}
```

Now you are filling and adding new instances and storing references to those in the list.